# How to convert scientific notation to string with full number laravel

Tags: php, laravel, export-to-excel

I've got a problem, I want to show the full number in excel but it shows the scientific number. already read another problem but still confused.
how can I show a row of full numbers?
[image: capture]

**export.php**

```
    public function collection()
        {
            return Staff::select('nik', 'nama_depan', 'nama_belakang', )->get();
        }
    
        public function headings(): array
        {
            return [
                'NIK',
                'NAMA DEPAN',
                'NAMA BELAKANG',
            ];
        }
```

Comment: Excel by default will convert what he believes is a number as scientific number. This is not a Laravel issue - you could export your NIK as strings instead of numbers

Comment: Change `\Maatwebsite\Excel\Writer` to `\Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomValueBinder` this may can solve your problem

Comment: @ChristopheHubert should i change the nik type on database?

Comment: @STA didnt change anything

Comment: udah nemu solusinya?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is that Excel will automatically convert any string looking like a number as a number.

You can add a single quote `'` before exporting to force Excel to recognize it as a string

```
public function collection()
{
    $collection = Staff::select('nik', 'nama_depan', 'nama_belakang', )->get();
    $collection->map(function ($item, $key) {
        $item->nik = "'" . $item->nik;
        return $item;
    });
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: new error "Object of class App\Staff could not be converted to number"

Comment: Yes it is fine, as long as you will not do any calculation on your NIK in Excel (Which I doubt). Don't forget to mark the answered as accepted so it can help others 